# How to write a type trait `is_container` or `is_vector`?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

Is it possible to write a type trait whose value is true for all common STL structures (e.g., `vector`, `set`, `map`, ...)?

To get started, I'd like to write a type trait that is true for a `vector` and false otherwise. I tried this, but it doesn't compile:

```
template<class T, typename Enable = void>
struct is_vector {
  static bool const value = false;
};

template<class T, class U>
struct is_vector<T, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, std::vector<U> > >::type> {
  static bool const value = true;
};
```

The error message is `template parameters not used in partial specialization: U`.

Answer (score 49):

Look, another SFINAE-based solution for detecting STL-like containers:

```
template<typename T, typename _ = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_container_helper {};

template<typename T>
struct is_container<
        T,
        std::conditional_t<
            false,
            is_container_helper<
                typename T::value_type,
                typename T::size_type,
                typename T::allocator_type,
                typename T::iterator,
                typename T::const_iterator,
                decltype(std::declval<T>().size()),
                decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
                decltype(std::declval<T>().end()),
                decltype(std::declval<T>().cbegin()),
                decltype(std::declval<T>().cend())
                >,
            void
            >
        > : public std::true_type {};
```

Of course, you might change methods and types to be checked.

If you want to detect only STL containers (it means `std::vector`, `std::list`, etc) you should do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105859/2842166).

UPDATE. As @Deduplicator noted, container might not meet  AllocatorAwareContainer requirements (e.g.: `std::array<T, N>`). That is why check on `T::allocator_type` is not neccessary. But you may check any/all [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) requirements in a similar way.

Comment: is_cointainer_helper can be replaced by std::void_t nowadays

Comment: For both `is_container` structs, `void` is used as second _parameter_. After tests, it seems that it works whatever the type, if this is the same type : `template<typename T, typename _ = int>` and `is_container_helper<...>, int>`. Why so? Why doesn't it work if we use `void` and `int`, or `int` and `void`?

Comment: Because you do use `is_container< Type >` which is `is_container< Type, void >` which is not specialised and default implementation is used: `std::false_type`

Comment: A *Container* might not be an *AllocatorAwareContainer*.

Comment: With use of `std::void_t` [you can trash](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EkXKcba58vfzjeF4)  `std::conditional_t`?

Comment: Yeap, but when I wrote this answer, there was a bug in GCC which breaks this method (SFINAE did not work in `std::void_t<...>`: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64395)

Comment: What is the `, class _ = void` part for?

Comment: how about `valarray<int>` and `forward_list<int>`?

Comment: @martian
Check [Container requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container). You may check any/all of them you need.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, after some trial and error I found it's quite simple:

```
template<class T>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T> > {
  static bool const value = true;
};
```

I'd still like to know how to write a more general `is_container`. Do I have to list all types by hand?

Comment: +1... duh! (maybe you want to add the `allocator_type` there also, the trait as it is is really `is_vector_with_default_allocator`

Comment: 6 years after :) Would you care to post a link to some on line ide where you have placed a minimal usage example? Thanks

Comment: @DusanJovanovic it is a type trait, you can look up any other type trait online and see how it is used. For example std::is_integral

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl this is wrong code. auto isv = is_vector<int>::value ; is explicit specialization of non-template struct 'is_vector' ... check

Comment: you need false general template first https://wandbox.org/permlink/76dOGKSuvEiBdAdw

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl exactly, this is why I asked to see the usage in the first place ...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl like [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D6Nf3Sb7PHjP6SrN)

Answer (score 20):

You would say that it should be simpler than that...

```
template <typename T, typename _ = void>
struct is_vector { 
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct is_vector< T,
                  typename enable_if<
                      is_same<T,
                              std::vector< typename T::value_type,
                                           typename T::allocator_type >
                             >::value
                  >::type
                >
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```

... But I am not really sure of whether that is *simpler* or not.

In C++11 you can use type aliases (I think, untested):

```
template <typename T>
using is_vector = is_same<T, std::vector< typename T::value_type,
                                          typename T::allocator_type > >;
```

The problem with your approach is that the type `U` is non-deducible in the context where it is used.

Comment: And for `is_container`? simply testing if it has an `allocator_type`?

Comment: @rhalbersma: The problem is what your definition of `is_container` is... Is my hand rolled `single_list` a container? is `std::string` a container? Does the fact that it has an allocator make an object a container?

Comment: I see your point. Writing out *all* STL requirements (all the standard iterator, value_type typedefs, all the member functions swap, begin, end, structors, operator ==, !=, etc. etc.) is torture. Bring on concepts!

Comment: for `is_container`, many people just look for `begin` and `end` functions, and use `is_iterable`, which is (most of the time) what you really needed to know anyway.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Where do I find `is_iterable`?

Comment: @Frank: Several random people have made `is_iterable` type traits, but they all do slightly different things, and nothing is standard.  Sorry.  I just meant, theoretically, if you're given an arbitrary container, you care less if it's _actually_ a container, and you _actually_ care if you can iterate over it's values, like with a `boost::range` of `boost::counting_iterator`

Comment: @homemade-jam: not quite following the reason for the comment. `enable_if` is in the C++11 standard library, it is also available from Boost from a long time ago, and it is simple enough that I actually type it many times in small tests or if the project needs to support C++03 and boost is not a dependency...

Comment: It just seemed a little confusing to me when the second solution says "and in c++11". No criticism, just comment.

Comment: @homemade-jam: :) in the question he is using `boost::enable_if`, so my assumption is that he is in a C++03 environment.

Comment: It is worth noting that the untested "using" syntax works only poorly in this case.  It will try to force an instantiation the dependent type "T::value_type" which will fail with a compile error if T is something like int.

Comment: This fails, with a complaint when T is not a struct, class or union type.

Answer (score 9):

Why not do something like this for is_container?

```
template <typename Container>
struct is_container : std::false_type { };

template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::list<Ts...> > : std::true_type { };
template <typename... Ts> struct is_container<std::vector<Ts...> > : std::true_type { };
// ...
```

That way users can add their own containers by partially-specializing. As for is_vector et-al, just use partial specialization as I did above, but limit it to only one container type, not many.

Answer (score 8):

While the other answers here that try to guess whether a class is a container or not might work for you, I would like to present you with the alternative of naming the type you want to return true for. You can use this to build arbitrary `is_(something)` traits types.

```
template<class T> struct is_container : public std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Alloc> 
struct is_container<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : public std::true_type {};

template<class K, class T, class Comp, class Alloc> 
struct is_container<std::map<K, T, Comp, Alloc>> : public std::true_type {};
```

And so on.

You will need to include `<type_traits>` and whatever classes you add to your rules.

Answer (score 4):

The way I like to detect whether something is a container is to look for `data()` and `size()` member functions. Like this:

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_container<T
   , std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().data())
      , decltype(std::declval<T>().size())>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: nice stunt. But this will "make" `std::string` (for example) into an container too . Using the above: `is_container<std::string>::value` is  `true`

Comment: as it should! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259595/c-is-a-stdstring-a-container

Comment: I was until now  believing `std::string` is not an std container? Although, I agree with [this text](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_container {

    template <
       typename U,
       typename I = typename U::const_iterator
    >   
    static int8_t      test(U* u); 

    template <typename U>
    static int16_t     test(...);

    enum { value  =  sizeof test <typename std::remove_cv<T>::type> (0) == 1 };
};


template<typename T, size_t N>  
struct  is_container <std::array<T,N>>    : std::true_type { };
```

Comment: says: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'test' in visual studio 2012

Comment: VC doesn't know about uint8_t

Comment: #include <cstdint> will allow it.

Answer (score 3):

Fast forward to 2018 and C++17, I was so daring to improve on @Frank answer

```
// clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17

 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

 namespace dbj {
    template<class T>
      struct is_vector {
        using type = T ;
        constexpr static bool value = false;
   };

   template<class T>
      struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> {
        using type = std::vector<T> ;
        constexpr  static bool value = true;
   };

  // and the two "olbigatory" aliases
  template< typename T>
     inline constexpr bool is_vector_v = is_vector<T>::value ;

 template< typename T>
    using is_vector_t = typename is_vector<T>::type ;

 } // dbj

   int main()
{
   using namespace dbj;
     std::cout << std::boolalpha;
     std::cout << is_vector_v<std::vector<int>> << std::endl ;
     std::cout << is_vector_v<int> << std::endl ;
}   /*  Created 2018 by dbj@dbj.org  */
```

The ["proof the pudding"](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cv5u9bZlwHbWWQpk). There are better ways to do this, but this works for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

We can also use **concepts**. I compiled this with *GCC 10.1* flag `-std=c++20`.

```cpp
#include<concepts>

template<typename T>
concept is_container = requires (T a)
{ 
    a.begin(); 
    // Uncomment both lines for vectors only
    // a.data(); // arrays and vectors
    // a.reserve(1); // narrowed down to vectors
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In our project we still didn't manage to migrate to compiler supporting C++11, so for type_traits of container objects I had to wrote a simple boost style helper:

```
template<typename Cont> struct is_std_container: boost::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_container<std::vector<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_container<std::list<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_container<std::deque<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename K, typename C, typename A> 
struct is_std_container<std::set<K,C,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename K, typename T, typename C, typename A> 
struct is_std_container<std::map<K,T,C,A> >: boost::true_type {};

template<typename Cont> struct is_std_sequence: boost::false_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_sequence<std::vector<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_sequence<std::list<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
template<typename T, typename A> 
struct is_std_sequence<std::deque<T,A> >: boost::true_type {};
```

Comment: `true_type` can be implemented without `boost`

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to make it work for const std::vector, you can use the following:

```
namespace local {

template<typename T, typename _ = void>
struct isVector: std::false_type {
};

template<typename T>
struct isVector<T,
        typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, std::vector<typename std::decay<T>::type::value_type, typename std::decay<T>::type::allocator_type> >::value>::type> : std::true_type {
};

}

TEST(TypeTraitTest, testIsVector) {
    ASSERT_TRUE(local::isVector<std::vector<int>>::value);
    ASSERT_TRUE(local::isVector<const std::vector<int>>::value);

    ASSERT_FALSE(local::isVector<std::list<int>>::value);
    ASSERT_FALSE(local::isVector<int>::value);

    std::vector<uint8_t> output;
    std::vector<uint8_t> &output2 = output;
    EXPECT_TRUE(core::isVector<decltype(output)>::value);
    EXPECT_TRUE(core::isVector<decltype(output2)>::value);
}
```

Without the std::remove_cv call the second ASSERT_TRUE would fail. But of course this depends on your needs. The thing here is that according to the specs, std::is_same checks for const and volatile to also match.

Comment: added std::decay to support references