# Can I define templates for different sets of types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, enable-if

I need to write a templated function, that behaves differently depending on the class of its parameter:

```
template<class ContainerType>
bool myFunc(ContainerType in){
//do some stuff
}

template<class NotAContainerType>
bool myFunc(NotAContainerType in){
//do something else
}
```

I am restricted to C++11, so `static_if` is off the table. Also, the classes of `ContainerType` and `NotAContainerType` are really large and might change in the future, so just adding a few exceptions by hand as a template specialization is not sensible either.

I am aware of the `std::enable_if` workaround, but how do I use it, if I need to apply it to two mutually distinct sets of classes?

Comment: How do you distinct those types of classes? Without that code, we can't help you much.

Comment: `std::enable_if`is exactly what you are looking for - so just define how you distinguish a "container" type from others.

Comment: @Jaa-c, I distinguish them just as their names suggest: ContainerType for std::containers (e.g. they have an iterator ), and NotAConatinerType for anything else

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Create a traits for your concept Container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12042824/560648), then, you might use SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value, bool>::type
myFunc(T in){
    //do some stuff
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_container<T>::value, bool>::type
myFunc(T in){
    //do some stuff
}
```

or tag dispatching

```
namespace details
{

    template <typename T>
    bool myFunc(T in, std::true_type){
        //do some stuff
    }

    template <typename T>
    bool myFunc(T in, std::false_type){
        //do some stuff
    }

}


template <typename T>
bool myFunc(T in){
    return details::myFunc(in, is_container<T>{});
}
```

Comment: tag dispatching for the win; so much nicer