# How to write a generic trait to match T::value_type against other traits?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a sort of "wrapper trait" that can detect, for some `T` and some existing unary trait `Concept`, that:

- `T` is "iterable", and
- `T::value_type` satisfies `Concept`

This is useful because I have other code that may expect various types, including `std::vector<various types>`, and I'd like to use this wrapper trait to `enable_if` various functions inside said code.

Here's a sketch:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>().begin() == std::declval<T&>().end())>> : std::true_type {};

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_iterable_v = is_iterable<T>::value;


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct iterable_value_type
{
    using type = std::false_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct iterable_value_type<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::value_type)>>
{
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};

template <class T>
using iterable_value_type_t = typename iterable_value_type<T>::type;


// Transforms a concept "does type T have property P" into the concept
// "is type T1 an iterable with value_type T2 where T2 has property P"
template <typename T, template <typename...> typename BaseConcept>
struct CollectionConcept
{
    static constexpr bool value = is_iterable_v<T> && BaseConcept<iterable_value_type_t<T>>::value;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<int>::value);
    static_assert(CollectionConcept<std::vector<int>, std::is_arithmetic>::value);
}
```

Unfortunately the second `static_assert` triggers and I can't work out why.

How can I implement this?

Comment: No ill will, but I'm voting to close as typo.

Comment: @PasserBy That's fair

Comment: OT: Being it called `is_iterable`, would be worth checking for `operator++` too?

Comment: @Bob__ Yeah maybe. To be complete it should be a bit more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207079/560648) tbf; this'll do for me for now though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit is this:

```
template <typename T>
struct iterable_value_type<T, std::void_t<decltype(T::value_type)>>
{
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};
```

You're applying `decltype` to a *type*, not to an expression.

To fix the trait, remove `decltype` (and prefix with `typename` because of name dependency):

```
template <typename T>
struct iterable_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>>
{
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d7e758ee51b5f3c)

Comment: Haha whoops. Thanks :P

Comment: Yep, full code works now with this [fixed] feature plugged in. Nice one

Comment: Do you think the approach is generally sound?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am a big fan of type traits for stuff, so "yes!". I can certainly imagine uses for such a trait.

Comment: Mine was adding valarray-like arithmetic capability to a variant that holds, among other things, ints and vector<ints>s. Using this trait I can select between implementations for those two type groups, and fall back on exception-throwing for anything else