# How to write a type trait method

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I defined a templated class (`DataArray<T>`) and I want to define a `min()` function to compute the minimum value of integral type array (`double`, `float`, `int`, ...) or complex type array (`std::complex<double>`, `std::complex<float>`, ...).

I am attempting to use type traits to select the correct function. Despite of the excellent discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042824/how-to-write-a-type-trait-is-container-or-is-vectorof), my code does not compile:

> ```
> DataArray<double> and DataArray<std::complex<double>>: no matching overloaded function
> ```

What is the problem? 
Here is the minimal part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class DataArray {
public:
    DataArray(T * data) : m_data(data) {}

    template<typename T>
    using isComplex = std::is_same<T, std::complex<typename T::value_type>>;

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<isComplex<T>::value>::type min() {
        std::cout << "Min for complex" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type min() {
        std::cout << "Min for arithmetic values." << std::endl;
    }

private:
    T * m_data;
};



int main()
{
    double v1[2] ={ 1., 2.};
    DataArray<double> d1(v1);

    d1.min();  // min function for double : **compilation error** 

    std::complex<double> v2[2] = { { 1, 2 },{ 3, 4 } };
    DataArray<std::complex<double>> d2(v2);

    d2.min();  // min function for complex<double> : compilation error 
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how do you implement min for a complex?

Comment: As Matlab did. The min function of a complex vector return the element with the smallest magnitude that you can compute with this code: template <typename X = T>
 typename std::enable_if<isComplex<X>::value>::type min() {
  std::cout << "Min for complex" << std::endl;
  auto min_ = std::abs(*m_data);
  std::for_each(m_data + 1, m_data + m_numel, [&](auto v) mutable {
   auto modulus = std::abs(v);
   if (modulus < min_)
    min_ = modulus;
  });
  //return min_;
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template parameter `T` of member templates shadows the template parameter `T` of class template. Give them another name; and specify default value for template parameter of `min()`, otherwise they can't be deduced. e.g.

```
template<typename X>
using isComplex = std::is_same<X, std::complex<typename X::value_type>>;

template <typename X = T>
typename std::enable_if<isComplex<X>::value>::type min() {
    std::cout << "Min for complex" << std::endl;
}

template <typename X = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<X>::value>::type min() {
    std::cout << "Min for arithmetic values." << std::endl;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u6SluhRVRtvUaIZ5)

Comment: O yes I am stupid. Thank you very much songyuanyao for your help.