# How to achieve overloads for containers and iterators for template function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I want 4 overloads of a template function. The function takes a range of values y and another range of values x. These ranges can either be specified as iterators or as containers. If passed as containers, the iterator functions are called for the container using `begin`/`end`. For x a special case exists, where passing a scalar x will be treated as if all x in the range [begin, end) are this value.

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>


// 1) Take iterator [begin, end) for y values and scalar for x
template <typename Iterator>
std::vector<double>
func(Iterator ybegin, Iterator yend, typename Iterator::value_type x = 1.) {}


// 2) take sequence of y values and scalar for x
template <typename Sequence>
std::vector<typename Sequence::value_type> 
func(const Sequence& y, typename Sequence::value_type x = 1.) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x);
}


// 3) take iterator [begin, end) for y values and iterator [begin, end) for x values
template <typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
std::vector<double> 
func(Iterator1 ybegin, Iterator1 yend, Iterator2 xbegin, Iterator2 xend) {}


// 4) take sequence of y values and sequence of x values
template <typename Sequence1, typename Sequence2>
std::vector<double> 
func(const Sequence1& y, const Sequence2& x) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin(), x.end());
}


int main() {
    std::vector<double> a{4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> b{1, 1, 1};
    func(a.begin(), a.end(), 0.2);
    func(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    func(a, 0.2);
    func(a, b);
}
```

The code I posted above doesn't compile because the call with `std::vector` and `double` fits for function 2) (correct) and 4) (incorrect).

```
error: call of overloaded ‘func(std::vector<double>&, double)’ is ambiguous
     func(a, 0.2);
                ^
scratch_1.cpp:33:44: note: candidate: ‘std::vector<typename Sequence::value_type> func(const Sequence&, typename Sequence::value_type) [with Sequence = std::vector<double>; typename Sequence::value_type = double]’
 std::vector<typename Sequence::value_type> func(const Sequence& y,
                                            ^~~~
scratch_1.cpp:50:21: note: candidate: ‘std::vector<double> func(const Sequence1&, const Sequence2&) [with Sequence1 = std::vector<double>; Sequence2 = double]’
 std::vector<double> func(const Sequence1& y, const Sequence2& x) {
```

If I use the following versions of 2) and 4), I get

```cpp
// 2)
template <typename Sequence>
std::vector<typename Sequence::value_type>
func(const Sequence& y, typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<typename Sequence::value_type>::value,
                                                typename Sequence::value_type>::type x = 1.) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x);
}

// 4)
template <typename Sequence1, typename Sequence2>
std::vector<double>
func(const Sequence1& y,
     const typename std::enable_if<!std::is_scalar<Sequence2>::value, Sequence2>::type& x) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

`error: no matching function for call to ‘func(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<int>&)’` because the type of the second vector can't be deduced.

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘func(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<int>&)’
     func(a, b);

candidate: ‘template<class Sequence1, class Sequence2> std::vector<double> func(const Sequence1&, const typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_scalar<Sequence2>::value), Sequence2>::type&)’
 std::vector<double> func(const Sequence1& y, const typename
                     ^~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Sequence2’ func(a, b);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`is_container`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207079/845092), which I have blatantly stolen:

```
// 2) take sequence of y values and scalar for x
template <typename Sequence, 
        std::enable_if_t<is_container<Sequence>::value, int> =0
>
std::vector<typename Sequence::value_type> 
func(const Sequence& y, typename Sequence::value_type x = 1.) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x);
}

// 4) take sequence of y values and sequence of x values
template <typename Sequence1, typename Sequence2, 
        std::enable_if_t<is_container<Sequence1>::value, int> =0, 
        std::enable_if_t<is_container<Sequence2>::value, int> =0 
>
std::vector<double> 
func(const Sequence1& y, const Sequence2& x) {
    return func(y.begin(), y.end(), x.begin(), x.end());
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90087c6a4c9b4901