# How to specialize template for containers and enums

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am trying to specialize a simple functionality for enum types and stl container types. The SFINAE idea is working for enum using enable_if, however similar technique for stl container doesn't work (I know that relying on existence of value_type and assuming it container is not a very good idea, but that is not the point here).

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct wrapper {
        static T getValue()
        {
            std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER DEFAULT VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
            return T();
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct wrapper<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>{
        static T getValue()
        {
            std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER ENUM VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
            return T();
        }
    };

    template<typename Container>
    struct wrapper<Container, typename Container::value_type> {
        static Container getValue()
        {
            std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER CONTAINER VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
            return Container();
        }
    };


int main()
{
    //En is an enum type
    En en = (En) wrapper<En>::getValue(); //Prints ENUM VERSION

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec = wrapper<std::vector<int>>::getValue(); //Prints DEFAULT VERSION
}
```

Please let me know why second call goes to default implementation?

### Solution:

Thanks to Sam Varshavchik, I figured out I was missing the point that second parameter should resolve to void (as it does in case of enable_if::type), or else I would have to explicitly pass second parameter to make my call resolve to container version:
`wrapper<std::vector<int>, int>::getValue();`

In order for original version to work (prior to C++ 17 where void_t is not available), I am creating my own type trait relying on the fact that containers have iterator type defined for them:

```
    template <typename T1, typename T2 = void>
    struct container_trait
    {};

    template <typename T1>
    struct container_trait<T1, typename T1::iterator> {
        typedef void type;
    };
```

and now my container version of wrapper becomes:

```
    template<typename Container>
    struct wrapper<Container, typename container_trait<Container, typename Container::iterator>::type> {
        static Container getValue(const rapidjson::Value& rjv)
        {
            std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER CONTAINER VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
            return Container();
        }
    };
```

And now the same call works perfectly fine:

`vec = wrapper<std::vector<int>>::getValue(); //Prints CONTAINER VERSION`

Comment: Your container specialization requires two template parameters (not void for second). Therefore it is never called in your examples. You might need to write a type trait similar to `is_enum` but for standard containers that contain `value_type` (as per your requirements), and then use it the same way. Look up `std::void_t` and how it is used.

Comment: Thanks @DeiDei, I ended up writing a type trait for containers that relies on the existence of value_type (though this reliance on value_type doesn't sound very convincing to me). but can't think of any better approach at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to check for `const_iterator` as it's more relevant to containers. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042824/how-to-write-a-type-trait-is-container-or-is-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the second call to the default implementation is very simple.

Simply work out by hand how the parameters get deduced for the container version template's parameters:

```
template<typename Container>
struct wrapper<Container, typename Container::value_type>
```

You are instantiating the following template:

```
wrapper<std::vector<int>>
```

So:

1) `Container` is a `std::vector<int>`

2) `Container::value_type` is `int`

Therefore this specialization becomes:

```
struct wrapper<std::vector<int>, int>
```

However you are invoking only:

```
wrapper<std::vector<int>, void>
```

because `void` is the default value for the second template parameter, so this matches the wrong specialization.

The solution is very simple, the container specialization should simply be:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Container>
struct wrapper<Container, std::void_t<typename Container::value_type>> {
```

`std::void_t` is C++17, there are other question on stackoverflow.com that explain how to implement it for earlier C++ standards. Complete example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum En {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct wrapper {
        static T getValue()
        {
        std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER DEFAULT VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
        return T();
        }
};

template<typename T>
struct wrapper<T,typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>{
        static T getValue()
        {
        std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER ENUM VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
        return T();
        }
};

template<typename Container>
struct wrapper<Container, std::void_t<typename Container::value_type>> {
        static Container getValue()
        {
        std::cout<<"\n WRAPPER CONTAINER VERSION IS CALLED.\n";
        return Container();
        }
};


int main()
{
    //En is an enum type
    En en = (En) wrapper<En>::getValue(); //Prints ENUM VERSION

    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec = wrapper<std::vector<int>>::getValue(); //Prints DEFAULT VERSION
}
```

Result:

> WRAPPER ENUM VERSION IS CALLED.
>
> WRAPPER CONTAINER VERSION IS CALLED.

Comment: Thanks Sam, your answer helped me reaching the point that I was missing here i.e. the second type should be resolved to void (as in the case of enable_if). And since I am not using C++ 17 so instead of void_t, I am now using type trait.
Btw, is there any standard way of specializing for stl container types? as I feel that relying on existence of value_type or iterator etc doesn't look very convincing to me.

Comment: Pretty much all containers define `value_type`. This is as good as any other approach.