# How can I overload a function wrapping STL data structures?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm writing a wrapper function that accepts some legacy data structures that don't use templates but would also like a variant for STL data structures.

```
  template<class DataType,
           std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<DataType, Array>>::value, int> = 0>
  auto MyFunc(DataType data) { ... }

  template<class DataType,
           std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<DataType, HashSet>>::value, int> = 0>
  auto MyFunc(DataType data) { ... }

  template<template<class DataType, class ValType,
           std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<DataType, ???>::value, int> = 0>
  auto MyFunc(DataType data) { ... }
```

How do I write the last function, so that it will accept std::vector and similar data types accepting one template parameter? I have it written here with SFINAE but I'm also open to function overloading. I'm using C++14.

Comment: "*similar data types*" What does that mean?

Comment: also accepts one template parameter, has the same typedefs defined (iterator, value_type, etc), has begin()/end() functions. So like std::set, std::dequeue, etc. I'd also accept a solution specific to std::vector, as long as the template parameter is still generic.

Comment: Can't it simply be an `||` like `enable_if_t<is_same<DataType, Array>::value || enable_if_t<is_same<DataType, HasSet>::value` etc.

Comment: Array and  HashSet above work fine already, as shown above. It's adding std::vector that I'm struggling with (and related data structures).

Comment: For SFINAE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043078/1863938, but this is perfectly achievable with a templated overload with a `vector<T>` argument... In general I'd recommend overloading over SFINAE if you can get away with it because non-template overloads will compile faster than templated ones.

Comment: Overloading is workable but I'll need 4 definitions of each, won't I? l-ref, r-ref, and const variants of each. SFINAE let's me use perfect forwarding.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair argument.

Comment: It's a good reminder tho. We always want the optimal solution but if I can't find one, then a good enough solution will suffice. I'm surprised there's still no answers to this question. Seems like a straight forward question.