# Compiling a function with templates fails in variadic template function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have come across a compiler error involving variadic templates. The following code is a strongly simplified version which reproduces the error in my original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> stringvec;

// dummy function: return string version of first vectorelemenr
template<typename T>
std::string vecDummy(const std::string sFormat, const T t) {
    std::stringstream ss("");
    if (t.size() > 0) {
        ss << t[0];
    }
    return  ss.str();    
}

// recursion termination
std::string recursiveY(stringvec &vFlags,  uint i) {
    return "";
}  

// walk through arguments
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string recursiveY(stringvec &vFlags,  uint i, T value, Args... args) {

    std::string sRes = "";
    if (vFlags[i] == "%v") {
        sRes += vecDummy(vFlags[i], value);
    }    
    sRes += " "+recursiveY(vFlags, i+1, args...);

    return sRes;
}

int main(void) {
    stringvec vPasta   = {"spagis", "nudle", "penne", "tortellini"};
    stringvec vFormats = {"%v", "%s"};

    std::string st = "";
    st += recursiveY(vFormats, 0, vPasta, "test12");
    std::cout << ">>" << st  << "<<" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This simple code should walk through the arguments passed to `recursiveY()` and, if the current format string is "%v" it would pass the corresponding argument to `vecDummy()` which would return a string version of the vector's first element (if there is one).

The error message from the compiler is

```
sptest2.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::string vecDummy(std::string, T) [with T = const char*; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
sptest2.cpp:30:25:   required from ‘std::string recursiveY(stringvec&, uint, T, Args ...) [with T = const char*; Args = {}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; stringvec = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; uint = unsigned int]’
sptest2.cpp:32:27:   required from ‘std::string recursiveY(stringvec&, uint, T, Args ...) [with T = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; Args = {const char*}; std::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; stringvec = std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; uint = unsigned int]’
sptest2.cpp:43:21:   required from here
sptest2.cpp:12:11: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘t’, which is of non-class type ‘const char* const’
   12 |     if (t.size() > 0) {
      |         ~~^~~~
```

It seems as if the compiler uses all types i pass to `recursiveY()` in main, but `vecDummy()` is designed to only work with vectors of some kind (and not with `const char*`, for example).

Is there a possibility to modify this code so that it will work as intended?

Is there perhaps a way of assuring the compiler that i will only pass vectors to `vecDummy()` (even at the risk of a runtime error or unexpected behaviour - similar to passing an integer to `printf()` when it expects a string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an overload of `vecDummy` that handles the `std::vector` case and 'dumb down' the more general one to (say) just return an empty string:

```
// dummy function: return string version of first vectorelement (catch-all)
template<typename T>
std::string vecDummy(const std::string, const T) {
    return "";
}

// dummy function: return string version of first vectorelement (vectors only)
template<typename T>
std::string vecDummy(const std::string, const std::vector <T> &t) {
    std::stringstream ss("");
    if (t.size() > 0) {
        ss << t[0];
    }
    return  ss.str();    
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/foSpxu7uDmc0IE5U)

Answer (score 1):

I think `if constexpr` can help here. I'm posting two solutions. (And a third, more complete one, at the end after an edit I did some time after posting)

First solution (only the function `vecDummy` changes). Here, `vecDummy` receives parameters of all types, doing its intended work only for vectors and doing nothing when the parameter is not a vector.

```
template<typename T>
std::string vecDummy(
    [[maybe_unused]] const std::string sFormat,
    [[maybe_unused]] const T t
)
noexcept
{
    std::stringstream ss("");
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, stringvec>) {
        if (t.size() > 0) {
            ss << t[0];
        }
    }
    else {
        // nothing, since this is intended to work only for vectors
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

Another solution is to move `if constexpr` inside `recursiveY` (and leave `vecDummy` unchanged). In this solution, `vecDummy` is only called for parameters of vector-type and when the format is `"%v"`.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string recursiveY(
    const stringvec& vFormats,
    std::size_t i,
    T value, Args... args
)
noexcept
{
    std::cout << "(1) i= " << i << '\n';

    std::string res = "";

    if (vFormats[i] == "%v") {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, stringvec>) {
            res += vecDummy(vFormats[i], value);
        }
    }
    else {
        if constexpr (not std::is_same_v<T, stringvec>) {
            res += std::string(value);
        }
    }
    res += " " + recursiveY(vFormats, i+1, args...);

    return res;
}
```

## EDIT

Following a question asked by OP in a comment, I've updated the solution to a more complete one in which `std::vector<int>` is allowed. Also, I've added the handling of the case "%s", which was lacking in the original post.

This update uses the construct `is_vector` that I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043020/12075306).

The result of this code is `>>spagis 1 1234 6789 test12 <<`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> stringvec;

/* ------------------------------------------------ */
// copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043020/12075306
template <typename T, typename _ = void>
struct is_vector {
    static const bool value = false;
};
template <typename T>
struct is_vector< T,
      typename std::enable_if<
          std::is_same<T,
                  std::vector< typename T::value_type,
                               typename T::allocator_type >
                 >::value
      >::type
    >
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
/* ------------------------------------------------ */

// dummy function: return string version of first vector element
template<typename T>
std::string vecDummy(
    [[maybe_unused]] const std::string sFormat,
    [[maybe_unused]] const std::vector<T>& t
)
noexcept
{
    std::stringstream ss("");
    if (t.size() > 0) { ss << t[0]; }
    return ss.str();
}

// recursion termination
std::string recursiveY
([[maybe_unused]] const stringvec& vFlags, [[maybe_unused]] std::size_t i) noexcept
{ return ""; }

template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::string recursiveY(
    const stringvec& vFormats,
    std::size_t i,
    T value, Args... args
)
noexcept
{
    std::cout << "(1) i= " << i << '\n';

    std::string res = "";
    if (vFormats[i] == "%v") {
        if constexpr (is_vector<T>::value) {
            res += vecDummy(vFormats[i], value);
        }
    }
    else {
        if constexpr (not is_vector<T>::value) {
            res += std::string(value);
        }
    }
    res += " " + recursiveY(vFormats, i+1, args...);

    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    stringvec vPasta        = {"spagis", "nudle", "penne", "tortellini"};
    std::vector<int> vMoney1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> vMoney2 = {1234, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<int> vMoney3 = {6789, 2, 3, 4};
    stringvec vFormats = {"%v", "%v", "%v", "%v", "%s"};

    std::string st = "";
    st += recursiveY(vFormats, 0, vPasta, vMoney1, vMoney2, vMoney3, "test12");
    std::cout << ">>" << st  << "<<" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you suggestions. However, my code must also run on a machine that can't handle C++17 (it's not my machine, so i can't change/update the compiler).

Comment: Also, this code is intended to handle vectors of various types (string, int,...). For this the constexpr part would need to be something like "std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<U>" for some unspecified type U. Would there be a construct that can do this?

Comment: I believe that with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71311108/12075306), you cannot handle the case of "%s" without compiler errors. Compiler errors will arise. Notice that in my solution (yes, with C++17) the result of your main is: `>>spagis test12  <<`. Answering your second question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043020/12075306) you will find the construct to detect vectors. I've updated my solution.