# Dealing with inconsistent typedefs in generic code

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, typedef, template-meta-programming

I routinely come across code in large codebases that do not follow the standard convention for typedefs e.g. `ThisType` instead of `this_type`.

Writing generic code where I can no longer rely on `this_type` means I have to provide some scaffolding code for each type that does not have `this_type`.

I suppose both `this_type` and `ThisType` can be defined. However, in a large codebase that adds extra noise and is something that reviews will need to routinely check.

Is there a way to wrap it in a `type_trait` such that I can write something along the lines of: `this_type<SomeType>::value_type` **OR** some other generic solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the scope of the problem. `auto` solves a major part of the problem. You use the keyword `typedef`, but C++ increasingly uses `using`-declarations instead. And those can be [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) nowadays.

Comment: @MSalters not sure how `auto` will help in situations where the generic code is doing something along the lines of: `typename T::value_type`

Comment: @Samaursa: I don't understand your question. If you're writing generic code, then your generic code defines a de-facto interface that the external world either already uses or is being required to use. The C++ standard library algorithms define an iterator interface that iterator types are required to implement, for example. If you provide an iterator that uses `ValueType` instead of `value_type`, you will get a compile error. The library defines the interface; users conform to that interface. You shouldn't *want* to allow people to use the convention they want when talking to your code.

Comment: Well, you typically do not see that in isolation. `typename T::value_type value = someExpr[0];` would be a full statement, where `auto` helps. There are quite a few other contexts where you do need type names, of course. `decltype` is another way to go from expression to type, which avoids naming `value_type`. See also the deprecation of `std::iterator` and the new `std::indirectly_readable_traits`

Comment: @NicolBolas Here's a non-contrived example of where you might want to use the typedef to construct a `type_trait`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207079/368599 - I don't think it's hard to imagine policy based metaprogramming relying on it as well

Comment: @Samaursa: Your problem is not what that code solves. Your problem is someone introducing some type into your system that doesn't provide the correct names for these features. Your example of `this_type` vs. `ThisType`. That's not a problem your code needs to correct; that's a problem with the user not providing the interfaces your code requested. Their code ought to conform to your code; your code should not conform to theirs. Note that the standard library does not allow you to spell it `ValueType`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure. However, in a large company it is difficult to convince multiple departments and multiple teams to switch over, especially when there is a lot of legacy code. Currently, they want all internal typedefs to be `CamelCase` while things that need to interop with stdlib use `snake_case`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe can be done in a simpler way... anyway, I propose a tag dispatching / SFINAE solution.

First of all, a simple recursive `tag` struct

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct tag : public tag<N-1u>
{ };

template <>
struct tag<0u>
{ };
```

to avoid ambiguities in cases more that one of the possible type names are defined.

Then a template function (only declared) for every type you want extract from the possible types; one for `type`

```
template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::type>* = nullptr>
typename T::type getType (tag<0u>);
```

one for `this_type`

```
template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::this_type>* = nullptr>
typename T::this_type getType (tag<1u>);
```

one for `ThisType`

```
template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::ThisType>* = nullptr>
typename T::ThisType getType (tag<2u>);
```

and one (to be a little silly) for `MySillyTypeName`

```
template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::MySillyTypeName>* = nullptr>
typename T::MySillyTypeName getType (tag<3u>);
```

Observe that the number of the `tag` are differents: this avoid the possible ambiguity and give a priority order for the names.

Now a trivial struct that uses `getType()` to extract the required type

```
template <typename T, typename U = decltype(getType<T>(tag<100u>()))>
struct GetType { using type = U; };
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t N>
struct tag : public tag<N-1u>
{ };

template <>
struct tag<0u>
{ };

template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::type>* = nullptr>
typename T::type getType (tag<0u>);

template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::this_type>* = nullptr>
typename T::this_type getType (tag<1u>);

template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::ThisType>* = nullptr>
typename T::ThisType getType (tag<2u>);

template <typename T, std::void_t<typename T::MySillyTypeName>* = nullptr>
typename T::MySillyTypeName getType (tag<3u>);

template <typename T, typename U = decltype(getType<T>(tag<100u>()))>
struct GetType { using type = U; };

struct foo1 { using type = short; };
struct foo2 { using this_type = int; };
struct foo3 { using ThisType = long; };
struct foo4 { using MySillyTypeName = long long; };

int main()
{
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<short,     GetType<foo1>::type> );
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<int,       GetType<foo2>::type> );
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<long,      GetType<foo3>::type> );
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<long long, GetType<foo4>::type> );
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you