# How to write a trait which checks whether a type is iterable

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, iterable

Is there any way to check if an arbitrary variable type is iterable?

So to check if it has indexed elements or I can actually loop over it's children? (Use foreach for example?)

Is it possible to create a universal template for that?

I've found techniques for other programming languages while searching for it. Yet still have to find out how to do this in C++.

Comment: Assuming iterability is expressed as a type, maybe RTTI?  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RTTI

Comment: Could you provide an example or two of what you're asking?

Comment: I'm using the Maya API and it's classes. You can iterate over its MVectorArray, MIntArray classes, but also the MVector, MPoint, MColor because they contain more than a single numerical value (or string for the MString/MStringArray).

Now I'm trying to create a template that supports adding (or multiplying, or dividing and more generic mathematical equations) any of the arbitrary values together. Which would mean for iterable elements to iterate over them and add a single element to each of its elements/indices. Does that make any sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match iterable types (arrays and classes with begin()/end())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224002/match-iterable-types-arrays-and-classes-with-begin-end)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "iterable". It is a loose concept in C++ since you could implement iterators in many different ways.

If by `foreach` you're referring to C++11's range-based for loops, the type needs `begin()` and `end()` methods to be defined and to return iterators that respond to `operator!=`, 
`operator++` and `operator*`.

If you mean Boost's BOOST_FOREACH helper, then see [BOOST_FOREACH Extensibility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/foreach/extensibility.html).

If in your design you have a common interface that all iterable containers inherit from, then you could use C++11's [std::is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
struct A : IterableInterface {}
struct B {}
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_iterable() {
    return std::is_base_of<IterableInterface, T>::value;
}
is_iterable<A>(); // true
is_iterable<B>(); // false
```

Answer (score 42):

You may create a trait for that:

```
namespace detail
{
    // To allow ADL with custom begin/end
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template <typename T>
    auto is_iterable_impl(int)
    -> decltype (
        begin(std::declval<T&>()) != end(std::declval<T&>()), // begin/end and operator !=
        void(), // Handle evil operator ,
        ++std::declval<decltype(begin(std::declval<T&>()))&>(), // operator ++
        void(*begin(std::declval<T&>())), // operator*
        std::true_type{});

    template <typename T>
    std::false_type is_iterable_impl(...);

}

template <typename T>
using is_iterable = decltype(detail::is_iterable_impl<T>(0));
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ExTsEO).

Comment: This is such a good example, it tought me a real good use of `std::declval`. Thank you very much!

Comment: this is `SFINE` for functions, and with `decltype` like above is the most elegant way for many different problems (why do we need any other way? use this and `enable_if` for everything). There is just one side note I have seen [here in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547654/sfinae-check-if-expression-compiles-and-return-stdtrue-type) about the need to stuff `void()` to break overloading `operator,`. It is not needed for this answer, but in general may be necessary in some cases.

Comment: @Jarod42, why do you have an `int` as the argument type in the declaration `auto is_iterable_impl(int)`? Also, what is the evil operator here?

Comment: @user2635088: `int` is used to provide order when both overload are viable. `f(int)` is a better match than `f(...)`.

Comment: We can overload `operator ,`, doing so might invalidate the test whereas it would be valid. (No match for `A(), B()` but `A()` and `B()` are both valid).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! Without it, I would never be able to create [this project](https://github.com/chariguanaCode/universal-print-in-cpp).

Comment: This is a good example I found in my search. But I am looking for a way to determine if a variable (or object) is iterable. So, something like `auto n;` `is_iterable(n)`. Is that possible? If yes then how?

Comment: @AbdurRakib: `template <typename T> bool is_iterable_func(const T&) { return is_iterable<T>::value; }` or `is_iterable<decltype(n)>::value`?

Answer (score 18):

[cpprefence has an example answering your question](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t). It is using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), here is a slightly modified version of that example (in case the content of that link gets changed over time):

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterable : std::false_type {};

// this gets used only when we can call std::begin() and std::end() on that type
template <typename T>
struct is_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>())),
                                  decltype(std::end(std::declval<T&>()))
                                 >
                  > : std::true_type {};

// Here is a helper:
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_iterable_v = is_iterable<T>::value;
```

Now, this is how it can be used

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << is_iterable_v<std::vector<double>> << '\n';
std::cout << is_iterable_v<std::map<int, double>> << '\n';
std::cout << is_iterable_v<double> << '\n';
struct A;
std::cout << is_iterable_v<A> << '\n';
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
```

Having said that, all it checks is, the declaration of `begin() const` and `end() const`, so accordingly, even following is verified as an iterable:

```
struct Container
{
  void begin() const;
  void end() const;
};

std::cout << is_iterable_v<Container> << '\n'; // prints true
```

You can see these pieces together [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b97389fbd3d2ac1)

Comment: the question was explicitly asked for C++

Comment: @Youda008 Now it works for plain C arrays too.

Answer (score 8):

If you are under the umbrella of C++11 and beyond, one usual way of SFINAE checking that works when you have to specialize for just one property, is the following one:

```
template<class T, class = decltype(<expression that must compile>)>
inline constexpr bool expression_works(int) { return true; }

template<class>
inline constexpr bool expression_works(unsigned) { return false; }

template<class T, bool = expression_works<T>(42)>
class my_class;

template<class T>
struct my_class<T, true>
{ /* Implementation when true */ };

template<class T>
struct my_class<T, false>
{ /* Implementation when false */ };
```

The trick is as follow:

- When the expression doesn't work, only the second specialization will be instantiated, because the first will fail to compile and sfinae plays out. So you get `false`.
- When the expression works, both overloads are candidate, so I have to force a better specialization. In this case, `42` has type `int`, and thus `int` is a better match than `unsigned`, getting `true`.
- I take `42` because it's the [answer to everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)), inspired by Eric Niebler's range implementation.

In your case, `C++11` has the free functions `std::begin` and `std::end` that works for arrays and containers, so the expression that must work is:

```
template<class T, class = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()))
inline constexpr bool is_iterable(int) { return true; }

template<class>
inline constexpr bool is_iterable(unsigned) { return false; }
```

If you need more generality, a way to express that something is iterable could also include user-defined types that brings their own overloads for `begin` and `end`, so you need to apply some `adl` here:

```
namespace _adl_begin {
    using std::begin;

    template<class T>
    inline auto check() -> decltype(begin(std::declval<T>())) {}
}

template<class T, class = decltype(_adl_begin::check<T>())>
inline constexpr bool is_iterable(int) { return true; }

template<class>
inline constexpr bool is_iterable(unsigned) { return false; }
```

You can play with this technique to achieve solutions that fits better your actual context.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes** using this [traits class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_%28computer_programming%29#Implementation) compatible [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)

```
template<typename C>
struct is_iterable
{
  typedef long false_type; 
  typedef char true_type; 
    
  template<class T> static false_type check(...); 
  template<class T> static true_type  check(int, 
                    typename T::const_iterator = C().end()); 
    
  enum { value = sizeof(check<C>(0)) == sizeof(true_type) }; 
};
```

#### Explanation

- `check<C>(0)` calls `check(int,const_iterator)` if `C::end()` exists and returns a `const_iterator` compatible type
- else `check<C>(0)` calls `check(...)` (see [ellipsis conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences))
- `sizeof(check<C>(0))` depends on the return type of these functions
- finally, the compiler sets the constant `value` to `true` or `false`

#### See compilation and test run on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/367f7781ac01f0da)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"set="<< is_iterable< std::set<int> >::value <<'\n';
    std::cout <<"int="<< is_iterable< int           >::value <<'\n';
}
```

#### Output

```
set=1
int=0
```

**Note:** C++11 (and C++14) provides many [traits classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) but none about iterablility...

See also similar answers from [jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230899/938111) and [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230850/938111).

<sub>This answer is in Public Domain - [CC0 1.0 Universal](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Or if (like me) you hate every SFINAE solution being a big block of dummy struct definitions with `::type` and `::value` nonsense to wade through, here's an example of using a quick and (very) dirty one-liner:

```
template <
    class Container,
    typename ValueType = decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Container>()))>
static void foo(Container& container)
{
    for (ValueType& item : container)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The last template argument does multiple things in one step:

1. Checks to see if the type has a `begin()` member function, or equivalent.
2. Checks that the `begin()` function returns something that has `operator*()` defined (typical for iterators).
3. Determines the type that results from de-referencing the iterator, and saves it in case it's useful in your template implementation.

Limitation: Doesn't double-check that there's a matching `end()` member function.

If you want something more robust/thorough/reusable, then go with one of the other excellent proposed solutions instead.

Comment: And in addition, what you propose here is bad style. You write the metafunction inline, intermingled with your implementation code. If you happen to need it several times, you will end up duplicating the metafunction code into each and every usage site. In what way do you think that is "better" than defining a clean self-contained traits template, and just call it as a library metafunction when needed? Note: the latter approach is what you put off as "nonsense to wade through"