# SFINAE check if expression compiles and return std::true_type

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I want to get std::true_type if the following expression compiles:

```
template<typename T>
static constexpr std::true_type check(T*) ??????
std::declval<T>().func_name( std::declval<Args>()... ) // method to check for
```

and std::false_type otherwise which I normally do with

```
template<typename>
static constexpr std::false_type check(...);
```

I search something like enable_if which returns me a constant type if the expression compiles. Seems so easy but breaks my head :-)

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<T>().func_name( std::declval<Args>()... ), void(), std::true_type{})`

Comment: Yep, that works, but never seen a decltype with 3 parms before... I will look for the manual. Thanks! Make it an answer so I can accept this!

Comment: @Klaus those are `operator,` not multiple parameters.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Call me crazy, but `void()` is a function type, not an expression - so that shouldn't compile. I think you meant `decltype(std::declval<T>().func_name( std::declval<Args>()... ), std::true_type{})`.

Comment: @Casey you're crazy :P `void()` is an expression of type `void`. It is there to prevent overloaded `operator,` from being selected.

Comment: @Klaus `decltype` just evaluates to the DECLared TYPE of a variable, or, if the thing inside the `()` is not a variable, to the type of the expression inside the `()`. Here, the expression is `something, void(), std:true_type{}`. That's three expressions separated by the comma operator. The last two are "casts in the functional notation", they create temporaries/values. `void()` creates a value of type `void`, and `std::true_type{}` creates a temporary of type `std::true_type`. The comma operator evaluates all expressions but "returns" only the rightmost.

Comment: OK, found that here it is simply used to get the type of the last expression. But why there is a ..., void(), ... in the middle? Is that only for fun? It would be nice to understand that :-) Thanks!

Comment: It's to break a potentially overloaded `operator,`. You can't overload with a parameter of type `void`, so `expr0, void(), expr1` always uses the built-in comma operator.

Comment: Wow! That is really hard to find out if there is no hint to that fact. Thank you very much for this tricky solution and the explanation! Great!

Comment: Check specifically [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/500104) in that question.

Comment: I think it is not really a duplicate. My questions goes to a detail of the solution you provided. What you wrote is one use case of the piece of code I asked for. But this doesn't matter, I got now all informations I searched for. Thanks for all the good explanations!

Comment: That note about stuffing `void()` to break `operator,` I only have seen it here, hidden in these comments!

Answer (score 0):

I personally use that (which use full signature):

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U, typename... Args>                                 \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }
```

So in your case, use something like:

```
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_func_name, T::func_name, void (T::*)(Args...));
```

And test it like:

```
struct C
{
    void func_name(char, int);
};

static_assert(has_func_name<C, char, int>::value, "unexpected non declared void C::func_name(char, int)");
static_assert(!has_func_name<C, int, int>::value, "unexpected declared void C::func_name(int, int)");
```