# How to check a type ignoring its template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

How do I determine the class type while ignoring its template parameters.

so for a fully specified type like `MyClass<param1, param2, ...>`, I want to check if it is indeed a MyClass type?

something in the spirit of

```
typedef ClassName<param1, param2, ...> T;

//Now my program receives T which can be any arbitrary type
//and I want to have something like the following
//check_if_MyClassType<T>::value should be true
//check_if_MyClassType<int>::value should be false
//check_if_MyClassType<T>::value should be false if T is not a MyClass type e.g T = vector<int>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious - have you studied how SFINAE is used in creating such tests ([first example found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547654/sfinae-check-if-expression-compiles-and-return-stdtrue-type)) and tried to apply that approach to this problem?

Comment: @RSahu I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @TonyD I do not fully understand the SFINAE solutions for type traits checking. Has relied on Boost type tarits library as black box till now which I guess uses SFINAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct IsMyClassType { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T> struct MyClass {};

template <typename T>
struct IsMyClassType<MyClass<T> > { static const bool value = true; };
```

Testing the above code...

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << IsMyClassType<int>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << IsMyClassType<MyClass<int> >::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << IsMyClassType<MyClass<float> >::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << IsMyClassType<MyClass<std::vector<float> > >::value << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T>
struct IsClassName { static const bool value = false; };

template <class param1, param2, ...>
struct IsClassName<ClassName<param1, param2, ...> > { static const bool value = true; };
```