# C++ parameter type to accept all sequences suitable for range-based for loop

Tags: c++, stl, containers

For example, I have a function like this which uses C++11 [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) syntax:

```
void myFunc(const std::vector<char>& bytes) {
    for (char b : bytes) {
        // do something useful to every byte
    }
}
```

How do I change this function declaration to accept every suitable sequence container, i.e. not only `std::vector<char>`, but also `std::array<char>`, `std::string`, etc?

From what I've learned, range-based for loops rely on existence of `begin()` and `end()`  methods for given `range_expression`. Typically, in other languages that means that all iterable containers share some kind of common interface that can be used to pass an arbitrary container for such parameter, but it looks like C++ doesn't have any container hierarchy like that. Instead, C++ seems to have "concepts", like [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container), but it's only accessible in compiler internals, I presume?

Comment: I think this SO question/answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164567/how-to-make-my-custom-type-to-work-with-range-based-for-loops

Comment: @Eljay This question answers kind of reverse of the question — i.e. "given existing for loop, how do I prepare my custom type to be accepted there". My question is given standard types, how do I prepare function to accept all these?

Comment: Templates are compile-time, static interfaces while [ABC](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/abcs#abc-defn)s, which are the only form of interfaces most other languages have, are run-time interfaces. Know the difference :) Concepts are just constraints on template types i.e. what can or can't be substituted to a `T`. It's yet to become a standard I believe.

Comment: @GreyCat This could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224002/match-iterable-types-arrays-and-classes-with-begin-end

Comment: C++ does not have a container hierarchy.  C++ for-in loop doesn't even has secret compiler internals.  C++ uses templates and SFINAE with both things like `std::vector::begin` and `std::vector::end`, or freestanding `begin` and `end` (such as `std::begin` and `std::end`), and the magic of ADL to try to find the begin/end iterators.

Comment: I normally don't recommend Wikipedia articles, but in this case, I think it would be a good idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B). The short story is that concepts are currently something like documentation and that attempts to turn them into a real, tangible compiler feature have been around for decades without them making it into any of the new C++ standards. Yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With concepts, you transform @rak007's

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(const T& bytes) {
    for (auto b : bytes) {
        // do something useful to every byte
    }
}
```

into the (infinitesimally) more explicit

```
template<Container T>
void myFunc(const T& bytes) {
    for (auto b : bytes) {
        // do something useful to every byte
    }
}
```

C++'s containers **already** conform to a (family of) common interface(s), but that interface is a *compile time* construct. What Concepts give you is in-language tools of specifying those interfaces, rather than in-documentation (or in specification) tools.

Comment: I'd also add that there are no such container concepts in the C++20 standard, only the range ones.

Answer (score 6):

I think this could do the trick

```
template<typename T>
void myFunc(const T& bytes) {
    for (auto b : bytes) {
        // do something useful to every byte
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just a plain templated function — this would offer no type checking except at the time of instantiation, and if this is to be placed into a library, I'll have to instantiate all possible type arguments for it anyway. Is there a better way?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your program is unclear. Could you give us more context ?

Comment: @GreyCat _How do I change this function declaration to accept every suitable sequence container, i.e. not only std::vector<char>, but also std::array<char>, std::string, etc?_  And this is the answer, use template. If you need something else, you need to be clear on your question. By the way, templates are meant to be placed in header files, not into libraries. If you need to put in libraries, think about inherintance

Comment: @GreyCat *this would offer no type checking except at the time of instantiation* That's the only time type checking is done.  Are you looking for something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fa29c2cc012a505) where the template is constrained?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think this was what he meant and thus should be the answer

Comment: @rak007 That's what I'm thinking.  I don't like the solution I came up with though.  IIRC support for different iterator types from `begin` and `end` has been added to ranged based for loops and my example would not allow that

Comment: @NathanOliver Yet the behaviour he is looking for is not recommended anyway so this could do the trick