# Template template parameters - why are they needed in this case?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out why the following piece of code, where a template of stream output operator function is written, requires using template template parameters:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/W85pV5GhVzI95b3e

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

template<template <class> class C, class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const C<T>& objs)
{
    for (auto const& obj : objs)
        os << obj << ' ';
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vf { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
    std::cout << vf << '\n';

    std::list<char> lc { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
    std::cout << lc << '\n';

    std::deque<int> di { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::cout << di << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Why can't I just write the template of the operator function like this:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, T& objs) {...}
```

In this case I get a lot of errors saying: 
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'const char')
             os << obj << ' ';

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Read the error message carefully. The type it's complaining about is not for any of the containers.

Comment: Suppose you use only vector, your function will have this signature std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const vector<float>& objs). So at least your template must have 2 arguments: the **vector** (for template<class> class C), and the type **float** (for class T)

Comment: But in this case I cannot use this function with an object of a non-template class in this case. That is not what I want. I would like my function to work with anything that is iterable, i.e. to accept objects of both template classes and non-template classes.

Comment: @YotKay - And so we reached the core of you [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Shame you didn't ask about *that interesting problem* instead of this obviously answerable one.

Comment: You are right, I should have asked this question differently. But fortunately we managed to solve this problem here and everything is now completely clear. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template template argument is not required.

Author of the code assumes that iterable object would be of that form `C<T>`, which is wrong:

- There exists `C<T>` that are not iterable, as `std::unique_ptr<T>`...
- `std::vector` has more arguments (defaulted) and so before `C++2a`, it won't matches `C<T>`.

using traits (like in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830158/check-if-a-variable-is-iterable)) would be better:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_iterable<T>::value>* = nullptr>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const T& objs)
{
    for (auto const& obj : objs)
        os << obj << ' ';
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I wonder why the error occurs in my case when I don't instantiate the template with anything non-iterable.

Comment: @YotKay You are using `operator<<` for float, int and char inside the operator itself.

Answer (score 3):

While I concur with **Jarod42** that you don't need the template template parameter, allow me to demonstrate a simpler solution for your specific case:

```
template<class T>
auto operator <<(std::ostream& os, T const& objs)
  -> decltype(std::begin(objs), std::end(objs), (os))
{
    for (auto const& obj : objs)
        os << obj << ' ';
    return os;
}
```

A trailing return type for some expression SFINAE, and everything works as you want it to. The SFINAE part happens in the `decltype()` return type. The comma operator makes it so `std::begin(objs)`, `std::end(objs)` and then `(os)` are checked as being well formed. If either of those is ill-formed, the function isn't considered for overload resolution. But because the type of the comma operator is the same type as its last operand, we get `std::ostream&` out of `(os)` due to `decltype` deduction rules.

Why `std::begin` and `std::end`? It just so happens that they are well-formed for pretty much all the types you can feed to a range based for loop. So the check is going to cover any type that adheres to the iteration protocol of a range based for loop.

[Here it is, live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ebd45f385af1a9b).

Answer (score 0):

You can not write the template like this:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, T& objs) {...}
```

because that would overload ostream for every(!) object.
T can be anything, not just a list.

I think the best way to deal with this is to specify the overload for each type of list that u want. 
E.g:

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T>& objs) {...}

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, std::list<T>& objs) {...}
```

and so on...

Comment: But that's what I want. I want a template which would work for anything, as long as it is iterable. Of course I want compilation to fail if I use this template with something non-iterable, that is obvious.

Comment: This is not as easy as you might think. Maybe this helps you to get in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830158/check-if-a-variable-is-iterable