# Iterate through template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, generic-programming

I have a function that receives a template parameter.

```
template<class Container>
void function(const Container& object)
{
     //here i want to iterate through object and print them
}

int main()
{
     function(std::vector<int>{1,3,6,7});
     function(std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,2,3},{2,5,7}});
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one function? Suppose the container argument will be integer.

Answer (score 7):

One example:

```
template<class T>
void print(T const& object) {
    std::cout << object;
}

template<class... Args>
void print(std::vector<Args...> const& container) {
    for(auto const& element : container) {
        print(element);
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
     print(std::vector<int>{1,3,6,7});
     print(std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1,2,3},{2,5,7}});
}
```

Comment: I'd name it `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, std::vector<Args...> const&)` rather than `void print(std::vector<Args...> const&)`

Comment: @Caleth That may cause issues with ADL and ODR because `operator<<` cannot be put into `std::` but its arguments are from `std::`. So that `operator<<` must be in global namespace, which may clash with other smart users defining the same operator.

Comment: *"in one function"*. nit picking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your case. Note that I'm using a trait as implemented here in this amazing solution by @Jarod42 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634934/8192043.

```
template<template<typename ...> typename C, typename D, typename ... Others>
void function(const C<D, Others...> &object)
{
    if constexpr(is_iterable<D>::value)
    {
       for(const auto& v : object)
       {
           for (const auto& w : v)
           {...}
       }
    }
    else
    {
       for (const auto& w : object)
       {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` has 3 template arguments, other containers have more or less. Your code can only work when the rest of container template arguments are the defaults.

Comment: We can overcome by replacing declaration with this `template<template<typename...> typename C, typename D, typename... Others>
void function(const C<D, Others...> &object)`

Comment: @arnes It should be just `template<class T> void function(T const& object)`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I think that that's not a constraint or restriction, just his attempt to print.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thought about this a lot and yeah, I come to the same solution as yours. Thanks, you have my +1.

Comment: Possibly: `template<typename Container>
void function(const Container& object)
{
    if constexpr(is_iterable<std::decay_t<*object.begin()>>::value) /*..*/`

Answer (score 0):

With [`is_iterable` traits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634934/2684539), you might do:

```
template<typename Container>
void function(const Container& object)
{
    if constexpr(is_iterable<std::decay_t<*object.begin()>>::value)
    {
       for(const auto& v : object)
       {
           function(v); // recursive call
       }
    }
    else
    {
        for (const auto& w : object)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```