# Non-overloaded C++ Function That Can Print a vector and a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Consider the following overloaded function that can print a 1d vector and a vector of vector of several types like strings, ints, doubles etc.

```
template<typename T>
void p(const vector<vector<T>>& vec) {
    int count = 0;
    for (vector<T> innerVec: vec) {
        cout << count++ << ": ";
        for (T e :innerVec) {
            cout << e << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}


template<typename T>
void p(const vector<T>& vec) {
    for (T e: vec) {
        cout << e << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Is there anyway I can merge these two functions into 1? I tried using SFINAE and tag dispatching but all the solutions I could come up with need a macro or multiple functions and I don't want this.

I know the question might seem odd since my solution works, but I prefer having just one function in my code. This is because I want to implement a function that can detect if I am passing in a map, vector, vector of vectors, unordered_set, multimap, etc and just print that STL data structure and having one overloaded function for each specialization is a bit annoying as it gets large quick.

Comment: Not a full solution, but you can replace the code duplication by, in the 2D version, just doing `cout << innerVec;` Also, I'd really recommend passing by `const &`

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<vector<T>> vec` is not a 2D `vector`. It is a `vector` that contains more `vector`s. There can be large performance implications because of this. The data is not all in one contiguous memory block, so it's not particularly cache friendly.

Comment: Because the behaviour of the two functions is different you'll have trouble merging the two functions You could do something like this: `template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out,
                          const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    for (T e: vec) {
        out << e << delimiter;
    }
    return out;
}` but the delimiter changes. You need some extra voodoo to detect when you're at a leaf, as in there are no more containers, so you can swap the delimiter. I admit to sucking at voodoo.

Comment: If you drop the `0: ` etc from the desired output, then you only need `template<typename Container, typename = std::void_t<typename Container::value_type>> std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Container& cont)` and `template<typename T1, typename T2> std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const std::pair<T1, T2>& pair)` to cover everything.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question today. Check it out there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60298735/8192043

Pasting the solution here:

> This should work for your case. Note that I'm using a trait as implemented here in this amazing solution by @Jarod42 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634934/8192043.

```
template<template<typename ...> typename C, typename D, typename ... Others>
void foo(const C<D, Others...> &object)
{
    if constexpr(is_iterable<D>::value)
    {
       for(const auto& v : object)
       {
           for (const auto& w : v)
           {...}
       }
    }
    else
    {
       for (const auto& w : object)
       {...}
    }
}
```

[Live Code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eT0amppKLJCBtN5b)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding the trait if possible. I don't want to add another function/class/struct just to be able to do something this simple. But clever idea so upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need an extra parameter to distinguish the inner from the outer case

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct counting_prefix {
    void call() { std::cout << count++ << ": "; }
    int count = 0;
};

struct no_prefix {
    void call() { }
};

template<typename T, typename Prefix = no_prefix>
void p(const T& e, Prefix prefix = {}) {
    prefix.call();
    std::cout << e << ' ';
}

template<typename T, typename Prefix = no_prefix>
void p(const std::vector<T>& vec, Prefix prefix = {}) {
    for (const T& e: vec) {
        prefix.call();
        p(e);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> stuff = { { 1., 2. }, { 3., 4. } };
    p(stuff, counting_prefix{});
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e76fe6dd273a13e9)