# decltype evaluating the wrong type from an expression list

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, decltype, comma-operator

while experimenting with the answer from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830158/check-if-a-variable-type-is-iterable),
ended up with the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
 
 namespace Test
 {
    struct MyPtr
    {
        double operator, (int Input)
        {
            std::cout << "Operator, called" << std::endl;
            return 1.0;
        }

        MyPtr operator* ()
        {
            std::cout << "operator* called" << std::endl;
            return *this ;
        }

        MyPtr operator++ ()
        {
            std::cout << "operator++ called" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }

        MyPtr operator!= (const MyPtr& Other)
        {
            std::cout << "operator!= called" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    struct Foo
    {
        MyPtr Ptr;
    };

    MyPtr begin(Foo& t)
    {
        return t.Ptr;
    }

    MyPtr end(Foo& t)
    {
        return t.Ptr;
    }
 }
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(++begin(std::declval<Test::Foo&>()),
                                 *begin(std::declval<Test::Foo&>()), 
                                  std::true_type{})).name() <<std::endl;
}
```

which yields:

```
d
```

Here, d comes from the comma operator. However, as the last expression inside the decltype specifier is std::true_type{}, why does the decltype specifier resolves to the type returned by the comma operator instead of std::true type.

My Theory is that std::true_type can be implicitly cast into an int, which operator,() here takes as a parameter, hence the decltype expression is equivalent to:

```
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(++begin(std::declval<Test::Foo&>()),
                                 declval<double&>())).name() <<std::endl;
```

Can you confirm this is correct?

What i am planning on doing when i will have a better grasp of the compiler's behavior, i plan on replacing the contents of the decltype specifier with:

```
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(void(++begin(std::declval<Test::Foo&>())),
                                 void(*begin(std::declval<Test::Foo&>())), 
                                  std::true_type{})).name() <<std::endl;
```

which will prevent operator,() from matching, even if it is overridden. Can you also confirm this is correct?

Comment: you could see what happens more easily by actually evaluating the expressions rather than using them only in unevaluted context

Comment: As that [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4G5nrc8vv).

Comment: if one operand is `void(..)`, then indeed user provided comma operator is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a member to `MyPtr` to get more information. Then actually evaluating the expression tells you what happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct MyPtr {
    int value;
    MyPtr(int x) : value(x) {}

    double operator,(int Input) {
        std::cout << "Operator, called value = " << value
                  << " Input = " << Input << std::endl;
        return 1.0;
    }
    MyPtr operator*() {
        std::cout << "operator* called value = " << value << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    MyPtr operator++() {
        std::cout << "operator++ called value = " << value << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    MyPtr operator!=(const MyPtr& Other) {
        std::cout << "operator!= called" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Foo { MyPtr Ptr; };

MyPtr begin(Foo& t) { return t.Ptr; }

MyPtr end(Foo& t) { return t.Ptr; }

int main() {
    Foo f1{10};
    Foo f2{20};
    ++begin(f1), *begin(f2), std::true_type{};
    ++begin(f1), *begin(f2), std::false_type{};
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/jrfdrnGnn):

```
operator++ called value = 10
operator* called value = 20
Operator, called value = 20 Input = 1
operator++ called value = 10
operator* called value = 20
Operator, called value = 20 Input = 0
```

Your "Theory" is correct. Lets remove the `++` and `*` to make it simpler, then you can think of `f1,f2,std::true_type{}` as `f1.operator,( f2.operator,(std::true_type{})`. `std::true_type` has `operator bool` and `bool` can be implcicitly converted to `int`. To illustrate that I also added the example with `false_type` in the code.

The `operator bool` can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) as `operator value_type`, because `std::true_type` is just an alias for `std::integral_constant<bool,true>`.

---

> which will prevent operator,() from matching, even if it is overridden. Can you also confirm this is correct?

Yes. It is not possible to implement an comma operator overload for `void`.