# Does the std container have a generic way of inserting into any container?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, containers

What I'm currently trying to do is extend the functionality of the C++ std containers. So I have done it like so

```
template<typename T>
class Queryable : public T
{
public:
    template<typename lambdaFunc>
    Queryable<T>Where(const lambdaFunc& w)
    {
        Queryable<T> whereVecObjects;

        for(auto iterObject = this->cbegin();
            iterObject != this->cend();
            ++iterObject)
        {
            bool add = w(*iterObject);
            if(add == true)
            {
                whereVecObjects.push_back(*iterObject);
            }
        }

        return whereVecObjects;
    }           
};
```

So what this class does is it accepts an std container in the template and creates a class that inherits from it. It then defines its functions that it wants to extend on the container.

Now this example I have provided above works fine if you are using `std::vector` like so

```
int main()
{
    Queryable<std::vector<int>> vecInt;
    vecInt.push_back(1); vecInt.push_back(2); vecInt.push_back(3); vecInt.push_back(4); vecInt.push_back(5); 
    Queryable<std::vector<int>> filteredVec = vecInt.Where([](int i){ return i > 3; } );
    for(auto iter = filteredVec.begin();
        iter != filteredVec.end();
        ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << ", ";
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this on a std::map I end up having an issue because of this line `whereVecObjects.push_back(*iterObject);`

Now I want a generic way to able to do the code above that would work on all the std containers.

Is there such a method?

Comment: No, you have to delegate to one for each container category.

Comment: Those who do not study Boost [Filter Iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) are doomed to re-invent them (badly).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks, but I have already looked at boosts version and it didn't do everything I needed. Please keep in mind the example provided above was specifically made to show my problem and it is not the whole class that I made.

Comment: It still seems to me that you're doing the job badly. In particular, a container should only contain. Trying to warp a container so it does things unrelated to containing objects is just a poor idea. Yes, I know it's been done many times before, and can initially seem like a good idea -- that's the sirens trying to lure you onto the rocks though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm now very curious, can you give me an example of how having some logic to go with a container can go badly?

Comment: The obvious problem is that you can no longer apply your logic to things that can be iterated, but aren't actually containers, or even your filtered subset of them is too big to just create a copy at will like you do here. Keeping the filtering in the iterator makes it easy to apply the filtration to (for one example) a file that might be a few hundred gigabytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use insert instead push_back.

```
whereVecObjects.insert(whereVecObjects.end(), *iterObject);
```

I think that you need more general Queryable

```
template <class T, template<class, class...> class Container>
class Queryable
  : public Container<T>
{
  // ...
}
```

Also I think you need to use Queryable only with containers. See [Determine if a type is an STL container at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407367/determine-if-a-type-is-an-stl-container-at-compile-time)