# Determine if a type is a container at compile time in c++98

Tags: c++

Is there a way to determine if a type is some sort of a container (probably with `begin()` and `end()` and forward iterators) in `c++98`? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407521/3162383) but it uses `decltype` from `c++11`.

Also making specializations for every container (list, vector, etc) is not that appealing - perhaps something more general?

Probably a duplicate... I'd imagine this used to be a common question

**EDIT**:

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers) is almost what I need and I should remove `tuple` stuff from it and replace the use of `std::enable_if` with c++98 code. What should I do with this question now? keep it open? or? If someone does that work for me I would be happy to accept his answer :D

Comment: What's your definition of "container" ?

Comment: I don't recall if SFINAE basics were included in C++98. If so, it should be possible to concoct something together, by hand, instead of using the canned C++1x language support templates. Dollars-to-doughnuts this is MS-Windows related. gcc on modern Linux has had excellent C++1x support for a long time.

Comment: @M.M not sure... maybe something with a ```begin()``` and ```end()``` and forward iterators?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik even for gcc I want my library to work with ```-std=c++98```

Comment: Usually the only distinction of interest is raw array versus container. And that's easy to check for via specialization.

Comment: Why do you want to make this determination? Your problem may have a different solution.

Comment: @GManNickG I want to provide a specialization of a template for containers that iterates over them - and the user will have to write specializations only for his types and not for the common containers

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just have the user pass begin/end iterators like standard algorithms, and if it's not a standard container, it's up to the user to provide iterators?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm doing expression decomposition (like [here](https://github.com/martinmoene/lest/blob/master/include/lest/lest_decompose.hpp#L286)) and all I have is the types of the left and right side of an expression (and I'm writing something similar to the ```to_string``` that dude has already done for containers)

Comment: @onqtam: That doesn't really answer the question. Is there any part of what you need/want to do that can't be done with iterators, or some other specific reason to deal directly with containers instead of using iterators?

Comment: `std::enable_if` doesn't rely on C++11 features, so you can just implement it yourself for C++03.

Comment: @JerryCoffin actually yes - iterators work fine for me - after having looked at the pretty printing of c++ stl containers question. But the user will not supply the iterators - I will detect if T has begin and end like [here](https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/blob/master/prettyprint98.hpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this - [cxx-prettyprint](https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/blob/master/prettyprint98.hpp) and will adapt it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can write specializations for all common containers that you want to support and fail compilation in the generic (non specialized) template.

There are not that many containers in the STL. Just about 15.

In this case your specializations will be picked up for common containers just by the regular mechanism and users will still be able use their own containers provided that they write required specializations.

There is other point about C++98/C++11. Compilers have not implemented all C++11 features in one step. For example `constexpr` was implemented by Microsoft only in VisualStudio 2015. If you try to run your code on a random compiler expect to see that some C++11 features are there, some features not.

It might be not a big mistake to use some of the features of C++11 provided that you know they were implemented early enough in the compiler that you are interested in.

Comment: so there is no way without listing them? no way to specialize on types with begin() and end()? this means boost containers (for example) won't work out of the box

Comment: You can check for presence of a function in the template parameter and decide that any class that has `begin()`, `end()` is container. Not very precise. User classes, that require specializations may be recognized as containers.

Comment: well c++98 is mandatory in my case - thanks for the effort though