# Static assert to check map, set, unordered_map, unordered_set

Tags: c++11, c++14, compile-time, static-assert

I am writing a function where I am copying Keys of `map`, `set`, `unordered_map`, `unordered_set` to a `vector`, now I want to add a compile time assert to get clear error if some try to pass a `vector`, `list` in that function.

```
template <typename container>
auto CopyKeyToVector(conatiner c)
{
  //static assert to check c is map, unordered map only?


}
```

Any idea how we can do that- as `map`, `unordered_map` itself templatized container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31105859/3953764

Comment: If you use `c` as it was an associative containers, i.e. only call a member function that only exists in e.g. `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`, then you will get a compiler error if the caller passes something which does not have that member function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement and use `is_specialization_of` as a generic solution:

```
template <typename, template <typename...> class>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type
{
};

template <template <typename...> class TTemplate, typename... Ts>
struct is_specialization_of<TTemplate<Ts...>, TTemplate> : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename container>
auto CopyKeyToVector(container c)
{
    static_assert(
        is_specialization_of<container, std::map>{} || 
        is_specialization_of<container, std::unordered_map>{}, "");
}
```

[**Full example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vilH0YmJ14yB3hOs).

---

Note that it can also be used with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_map_or_umap = 
    is_specialization_of<T, std::map>{} || 
    is_specialization_of<T, std::unordered_map>{};

template <typename container>
auto CopyKeyToVector(container) -> std::enable_if_t<is_map_or_umap<container>>
{
    // (1)
}

template <typename container>
auto CopyKeyToVector(container) -> std::enable_if_t<!is_map_or_umap<container>>
{
    // (2)
}

int main()
{
    CopyKeyToVector(std::map<int,float>{});           // Calls (1) 
    CopyKeyToVector(std::unordered_map<int,float>{}); // Calls (1)
    CopyKeyToVector(std::vector<int>{});              // Calls (2)  
}
```

[**Full example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jrLRdPo1JrWQR1hC).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use static assertions. Instead, add one level of indirection:

```
template <typename C>
void CopyKeyToVectorImpl(const C& c) { /* ... */ }

template <typename K, typename T, typename Pred, typename Alloc>
void CopyKeyToVector(const std::map<K, T, Pred, Alloc>& m) {
  CopyKeyToVectorImpl(m);
}

template <typename K, typename T, typename Hash, typename Eq, typename Alloc>
void CopyKeyToVector(const std::unordered_map<K, T, Hash, Eq, Alloc>& m) {
  CopyKeyToVectorImpl(m);
}
```

(You can modify the `Impl` function further to allow sets in the same wash by parametrising the value-to-key projection.)

Comment: Won't the error message be a verbose "can't find overload" as opposed to the `static_assert`s concise "must pass map, unordered_map,..." message?

Comment: @StoryTeller A compiler error in tandem with using a function named `CopyKeyToVector` should definitely give quite the clue, should it not? It could be a bit misleading if passing in say a `std::set` or the like, but I think it's probably clear enough.

Comment: @erip, I disagree. But the subject of error message clarity is subjective, so I won't argue the point.

Comment: @StoryTeller: well... depends how you see it. With my proposal, the supported overloads of `CopyKeyToVector` would appear in the publicly documented synopsis; the accepted set of types is part of the signature, not of the implementation. But indeed the diagnostic is different from what the OP asked for.