# Enable a struct if enable_if determines that T is a container?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to build a templated struct that will only take containers for `T`. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407521) that showed how to determine whether the passed in value is a container or not. So I decided to go ahead and try to use that for my program as I do not want the user to create a struct of integers, floats, or doubles.

Here is code that I have written:

```
template<typename T> 
struct is_container : std::integral_constant<bool, has_const_iterator<T>::value && has_begin_end<T>::beg_value && has_begin_end<T>::end_value> { };

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Cont;

template <typename T>
struct Cont<T, typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>>
{
  Cont(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}
  std::string name;
};
```

However, when I try to write to main:

```
int main()
{
  Cont<std::vector<int>> myContainer("Vector");
}
```

I get a compiler error: `Cont<std::vector<int> > myContainer has initializer but incomplete type.` I'm kind of stuck on where to go with this, because if I remove the `std::enable_if` from the template parameter, it compiles just fine. Which leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong with `std::enable_if` or I am missing something rather simple.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
int main()
{
  Cont<std::vector<int>> myContainer("Vector"); //happily compiles
  Cont<int> badContainer("Bad"); // will not compile
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong with `std::enable_if` or I am missing something rather simple.

Exactly.

You have forgotten a `::type`

```
template <typename T>  // add this ---------------------------vvvvvv
struct Cont<T, typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>::value>::type>
{
  Cont(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}
  std::string name;
};
```

Starting from C++14, you can also use `std::enable_if_t` (so you can remove the `::type` and the preceding `typename`)

```
template <typename T>
struct Cont<T, std::enable_if_t<is_container<T>::value>>
{
  Cont(const std::string &n) : name(n) {}
  std::string name;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not know I needed `type` at the end. However, I decided to go with the `std::enable_if_t` option since it looks a lot cleaner.