# Is it possible to use constexpr if to check if the type is a container or a std::string

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, metaprogramming

For example I have this class:

```
template <typename T, U>
class TLVParser
{
public:
    TLVParser(T value) : value_(std::move(value)) {}
    void parse(const std::span<uint8_t> &buffer, size_t &offset)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
        {
            return parsePrimitive(buffer, offset);
        }
        else if constexpr
            constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string> || std::is_same_v<T, std::string_view>)
            {
                return parseStringView(buffer, offset);
            }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::span<U>> || std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<U>>)
        {
            return parseContainer(buffer, offset);
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "Unsupported type for TLV parsing");
        }
    }

private:
    T value_;
};
```

As I understand, `string_view`, `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::span` has some common properties that I could make the same  parse function. So is there a way to use `if constexpr` to check if this type is a container like this ones without writing a `||` for each one, and just using a concept to garantee that this container should have a specific propertie like capable of range loop?

My second question is can I make a typename for the `std::span<uint8_t>` parameter so I can use a `std::vector`, `std::array` or even `uint8_t*` or `char*` ?

Comment: The tricky part is to come up with a concise definition of what a "container" is. For the sake of argument, let's say: if it has a `begin()` or the `end()` then it's a container (and `std::string` would qualify). Based on the shown code, above, it looks like you'll be able to write the appropriate `constexpr` without any further help.

Comment: what are the exact requirements that make those types ok for the same parse function? Write those requirements down as a concept and use it. Then also any other user supplied type will work if it meets the requirements. The type must have `begin(x)` and `end(x)`, what else?

Comment: the code you posted is bogus. return type is `void`, on some branches you return something on others not. `template <typename T, U>` is not correct syntax....

Comment: [Determine if a type is an STL container **at compile time**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407367/determine-if-a-type-is-an-stl-container-at-compile-time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a couple of people already pointed out in the comments, determining what constitutes a "*container*" is often the issue. One way is checking if it supports "*std::begin()*" and "*std::end()*", which also handles C-style arrays, opposed to just checking for classes that have members "*begin()*" and "*end()*" (which would ignore C-style arrays).

Here's another technique however which I prefer for reasons I won't get into here (for C++17 and later though it can be slightly tweaked to handle earlier versions). It simply checks if it's a class that has an "*iterator*" or "*const_iterator*" alias (typedef), in addition to a C-style array. The use of the macro is ugly but it's just to create the type safe code that does the work of checking for "*iterator*" or "*const_iterator*" (and the macro can be used to create type safe "*HasMemberType_?*" classes to detect any other type alias as well if required, not just "*iterator*" or "*const_iterator*"). Concepts are also now available of course (in C++20) so you can also create a concept that just defers to "*IsContainer_v*" if you wish (see this below). Some of the "*std*" concept classes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) can also likely be leveraged for those that want to implement something more modern (but I won't start tackling that here).

Anyway, the following code wouldn't qualify for the standard itself but works *very* well in practice (and yes, it handles "*std::string*" if required since it has the necessary iterator aliases).

Click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjco4K4Kc) to run it.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_TYPE(NAME) \
    template <typename, typename = void> \
    struct HasMemberType_##NAME : std::false_type \
    { \
    }; \
    template <typename T> \
    struct HasMemberType_##NAME<T, std::void_t<typename T::NAME>> : std::true_type \
    { \
    }; \
    template <typename T> \
    inline constexpr bool HasMemberType_##NAME##_v = HasMemberType_##NAME<T>::value;

DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_TYPE(iterator)
DECLARE_HAS_MEMBER_TYPE(const_iterator)

template <typename T>
using IsContainer = std::bool_constant<HasMemberType_const_iterator_v<T> ||
                                       HasMemberType_iterator_v<T> ||
                                       std::is_array_v<T>>;

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool IsContainer_v = IsContainer<T>::value;                                       

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsContainer_v<std::vector<int>> << "\n"; // true
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsContainer_v<int []> << "\n"; // true (C-style array)
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsContainer_v<int *> << "\n"; // false (pointer not considered a container)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, the macro is much more readable (imho) and looks much less massive if you use newlines more sparingly https://godbolt.org/z/P8G7WrvKh

Comment: A cosmetic issue but in this case you're probably right (will just leave it as is so others can contrast the two but thanks for the recommendation :)