Convert template argument to template template
I have following, simplified code. The question is, is there any way to recognize A::v_ and value parameter as an container type and call the right convert function? Or the rework need to be done? In case of rework do you have any suggestions how to deal with such problem most efficiently?
template <typename A, typename B>
B convert(A a)
{
   return B{a};
}

template <template <typename A> typename CA, typename A, typename B>
B convert(CA<A> a)
{
   return B{a.first()};
}

template <typename A, template <typename B> typename CB, typename B>
CB<B> convert(A a)
{
   CB<B> cb; cb.push_back(static_cast<B>(a));
   return cb;
}

template <template <typename A> typename CA, typename A, template <typename B> typename CB, typename B>
CB<B> convert(CA<A> a);

template <typename T>
struct A
{
   T v_;

   template <typename U>
   void assign(const A<U>& value)
   {
      // How to recognize if "value" and "this->v_" is an container
      // and call right "convert" function
      // if constexpr (???)
      //    v_ = convert<value container, value element, this->v_ container, this->v_ element>(value);
      // else if constexpr (???)
      //    v_ = convert<value type, this->v_ container, this->v_ element>(value);
      // else if constexpr (???)
      //    v_ = convert<value container, value element, this->v_ type>(value);
      // else
      //    v_ = convert<value type, this->v_ type>(value);
   }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   A<int> i;
   A<std::vector<int> > vi;

   vi.assign(i);
}

I tried to search for converting template arguments to template-template but with no luck.

Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65308090/4123703 requires C++20.

@LouisGo Partially. How to extract bare std::vector for container type parameter?

Please add a user code for how you want to use the template. Also please make template argument more redable...  Also ??? should be elaborated on what you want to check.

@LouisGo main function added, As I mentioned I want to recognize container arguments and non-container arguments - that's what conecepts actually do. But to call correct convert I need also bare container type extraction

For fun you can do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qfjqd68oM. But I don't see any practical usage as, ASFAK, you can not get Cont out of Extractor .  But with a small addition, you can get instances of Cont from Extractor if needed.

@Oersted Ok, I guess it is just impossible and rework need to be done. I think Extractor has no use case here, because I need to put something making bare std::vector in the first template argument.

I can't get why you can't use the full type of the container to select your convert function (Make convert a functor then you can have a specialization for vector, list,... : something in the spirit of template<typename T,typename ... Other> class convert<std::vector<T,Other...>>{...};

You might reorder template argument so A might be deduced.

@Oersted I want to have two different template functions, the one treating container types and another treating non container types. These two functions will be slightly different, because containers has different API. If I put the full type into template arguement - the non container version will be called for container type.

@Jarod42 Could you send the simple example, because I don't get it.

In which way CB<B> convert(A a); and B convert(A a); differs? especially when convert<A, CB<B>> might do what the former overload do.

With template <typename B, typename A> B convert(A a); call would be simpler: C c = convert<C>(some_obj);

@Jarod42 I edited the code, hope it anserws your question.

I want to have two different template functions, the one treating container types and another treating non container types. Then 2 overloads, using Jarod42 concept will do the job

@Jarod42 Could you please make a simple example, as an answer?

template<Container C> convert(const C& obj); : https://godbolt.org/z/1GvfYzcad

@Oersted Yes - this does the job. Thank you. I will accept such answer. But not sure who is the author.

@LouisGo Actually your suggestion was helpful, but I didn't get it because I didn't know how to use the concepts.

LouisGo and Jarod42 did the trick. I just show you how to put the pieces together.

CB<B> convert(A a) and B convert(A a) are similar and can IMO be regrouped in the later.
Reorder template parameter to have deducible type at the end would also simplify the call.
With all that, A would simply be:
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T v_{};

    template <typename U>
    void assign(const A<U>& value)
    {
        v_ = convert<T>(value.v_);
    }
};

Then for the different case, using tag dispatching:
// Customization points
template <typename To, typename From>
To convert_to(std::type_identity<To>, From a)
{
   return To{a};
}

template <typename To, template <typename> class Cont, typename T>
To convert_to(std::type_identity<To>, Cont<T> a)
{
   return To{a.front()};
}

// Same implementation than convert_to(std::type_identity<To>, From a)
// so might be omitted here.
template <template <typename> class Cont, typename T, typename From>
Cont<T> convert_to(std::type_identity<Cont<T>>, From a)
{
   return Cont<T>{a}; 
}

// Better would be to check class capabilities (have back()/begin()/end()/...)
// instead of a generic Cont<T>.
// Below A<T> won't fulfil the requirement for example.
template <template <typename> class Cont, typename T, template <typename> class Cont2, typename T2>
Cont<T> convert_to(std::type_identity<Cont<T>>, Cont2<T2> a)
{
   return Cont<T>{a.back()};
}

// Entry point
template <typename To, typename From>
To convert(From a)
{
   return convert_to(std::type_identity<To>{}, a);
}

Demo
or if constexpr (C++17) (and concept C++20):
template <typename T>
concept Container = requires (T t)
{
    t.begin();
    t.end();
    t.front();
    t.back();
    //...
};

template <typename To, typename From>
To convert(From a)
{
    if constexpr (Container<To>) {
        if constexpr (Container<From>) {
            return To{a.front()};
        } else {
            return To{a};
        }
    } else {
        if constexpr (Container<From>) {
            return To{a.back()};
        } else {
            return To{a};
        }
    }
}

Demo

concept version, Wouldn't be nicer to apply Container concept as a template argument? As @Oersted suggested

@Nabuchodonozor: You might adapt Container concept to your needs, both shown are not perfect.

is there a standard concept for each name requirement in C++? For instance, "sequence container" would be a good fit.

Thanks to @Jarod42 @LouisGo and @Oersted, I understood that the concept solution would be the best. My solution is
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept Container = requires(T t) {
    std::begin(t);
    std::end(t);
};

template <typename A, typename B>
B convert(A a)
{
   return B{a};
}

template <Container A, typename B>
B convert(A a)
{
   return B{a.front()};
}

template <typename A, Container B>
B convert(A a)
{
   return B{};
}

template <Container A, Container B>
B convert(A a)
{
   return B{};
}

template <typename T>
struct A
{
   T v_{};

   template <typename U>
   void assign(const A<U>& value)
   {
     v_ = convert<U, T>(value.v_);
   }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   A<int> i;
   A<std::vector<int> > vi;

   vi.assign(i);

   return 0;
}


I suggest to change order of A and B in template parameter (i.e template <Container B, Container A>, as A is deducible), and so v_ = convert<T>(value.v_);.
