# how to write this in vs12?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading [post "64bit" on The AdaptiveRisk Blog](https://blog.adaptiverisk.com/post/2016-12-01-64bit/), where the sample code has a line can't be compiled in visual studio 2013:

```
/*!
@brief Helper to determine whether there's a key_type for T.
@sa http://stackoverflow.com/a/7728728/266378
*/
template<typename T>
struct has_mapped_type
{
private:
  template<typename C> static char test(typename C::mapped_type*);
  template<typename C> static char(&test(...))[2];
public:
  static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;
};
```

Here `static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == 1;` using constexpr could not be compiled. Simply removing `constexpr` doesn't work, VS reports error C2864:

> 'nlohmann::`anonymous-namespace'::has_mapped_type::value' : a
>   static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile
>   const integral type

Is there a way to rephrase it so that VS 2013 could compile?

Comment: VS 2013 lacks support for constexpr: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: Does it have to be static?

Comment: @AndyG exactly. so my question is if it's possible to **rephrase** it.

Comment: Try `static const`

Comment: thx! @doctorlove 's way works!

Comment: @athos: It does appear to work for me, too, even though expression SFINAE is not officially supported in VS 2013