# Defining a function so that it can accept either a list or a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function which needs to receive either an `std::list` or an `std::vector` of `MyClass *` objects and do a bunch of processing depending on what's inside.
I don't want to duplicate the function body.

I only need to use these objects to iterate over them and do some read-only checks.

I had thought of passing `.begin()` and `.end()` iterators directly, but that doesn't seem pretty at all.

Is there a better way to get around this, currently I have the following solution (which creates another list out of the vector being passed, which is hardly ideal either).

```
void process(std::list<MyClass*> input)
{
    //A lot of processing
    BOOST_FOREACH(MyClass* itMyClass, input)
    {
        //some checks, creating new list based on the checks      
    }
    //A lot of processing
}
void process(std::vector<MyClass*> input)
{
    process(std::list<MyClass*>(input.begin(), input.end()));
}
```

EDIT:

It seems that many people are suggesting to go for `begin()` and `end()` after all, I've made it work in a way similar to the example below. Thanks for your help.

```
//This one is private
template <typename Iterator>
void process(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    //A lot of processing
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) 
    {
        //some checks, creating new list based on the checks
    }
    //A lot of processing
}
void process(std::list<MyClass*> input)
{
    process(input.begin(), input.end());
}
void process(std::vector<MyClass*> input)
{
    process(input.begin(), input.end());
}
```

Comment: Use a template?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728478/c-template-class-function-with-arbitrary-container-type-how-to-define-it

Comment: Even though iterators don't look pretty they are consistent with the standard library and very versatile. It is worth reconsidering your stance on them.

Comment: I also vote for passing *begin* and *end* iterators directly. It is the best way to decouple your algorithm from the containers you want to process. The `STL` is a work of genius, even if it doesn't always look pretty.

Comment: Alternatively, you could pass in a begin and end iterator, rather than the container.  (Which works if you are iterating, but not so much if you are mutating the container.)

Comment: It seems that begin() and end() is the people's choice, and it was my first thought too.
I believe I'll have two public overrides, one for vector, one for list, and both will pass begin() and end() iterators to private function which will have the logic.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) for that:

```
template<class ListOrVector>
void process(ListOrVector const& input) {
    //your code
}

//You can also use a template template parameter
template<template<class My, class Alloc = std::allocator<My>> class ListOrVector>
void process(ListOrVector<MyClass*, Alloc> const& input) { ... }
```

Note that I take the ListOrVector by const reference (The `const &`). This will prevent a copy.

**EDIT**

I have fixed the second example. The `class`before the ListOrVector was missing and the allocator is `std::allocator<My` by default.

Comment: @YuKo You probably do not care about the allocator at all. So you could simplify it to: template<template<class My> class ListOrVector> void process(ListOrVector<MyClass*> const& input)

Answer (score 0):

Just like ordinary functions, *function templates* can also be *overloaded*, so that you can have the best of both worlds: an *iterator-based* algorithm for more flexibility and a *container-based* one for the ease of use.

This way, you can use the iterator-based overload for processing a subrange of a container and the container-based one for processing all the elements of a container.

---

#### `process(first, last)`

I would suggest first defining a function template `process()` that takes an *iterator pair* for the sequence of elements you want to process:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void process(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
   for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
      // ...
   }
}
```

This is an *iterator-based* algorithm (i.e., it takes an iterator pair), and corresponds to the same approach the STL algorithms follow.

---

#### `process(container)`

Then, I would define another function template `process()` that *overloads* the first one. This overload takes a container and calls the iterator-based version of `process()` on the elements of the passed container:

```
template<typename Container>
void process(Container const& c) {
   process(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

This is a *container-based* algorithm, since it takes a container.

---

This way, you can use a *container-based* algorithm instead of an iterator-based one:

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
std::list<int> lst{1, 2, 3};
std::array<int, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};
int carr[] = {1, 2, 3};

process(vec);
process(lst);
process(arr);
process(carr);
```

This algorithm is decoupled from the containers to process (e.g., it works even with C-style arrays, as you can see), yet you call it directly on a container instead of passing iterators.

You can always call the overload of `process()` that takes an iterator pair instead of a container when you don't want to process all the elements of a container, but just a subrange of the elements in it.