# Can a function template deduce a container's value type?

Tags: c++, qt, templates

Suppose I define the following function template that removes an item from the given set if the specified function returns true for that item.

```cpp
template<typename TYPE>
int removeItems(
    QSet<TYPE>& set,
    const std::function<bool (const TYPE&)>& shouldRemove)
{
    int numRemoved = 0;

    auto iter = set.begin();
    while (iter != set.end())
    {
        if (shouldRemove(*iter))
        {
            iter = set.erase(iter);
            ++numRemoved;
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }

    return numRemoved;
}
```

I can use this function template like this:

```cpp
QSet<QString> stuff = {"A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c"};
removeItems<QString>(stuff, [](const QString& thing) {
    return thing.toLower() == "a";
});
qDebug() << stuff; // QSet("B", "b", "C", "c")
```

But can the function template be defined in such a way that the template argument can be omitted from the function call?

```cpp
QSet<QString> stuff = {"A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c"};
removeItems(stuff, [](const QString& thing) {
    return thing.toLower() == "a";
});
qDebug() << stuff; // QSet("B", "b", "C", "c")
```

Comment: I don't have a real object, but you could use a QObject base instead to accept and then try to cast it inside using a dynamic cast.

Comment: I think this could be done with a template template, e.g. `template <template <typename> typename Container, typename Value> removeItems(Container<Value>& set, ...) {...}`

Comment: This shows how you can set templates for stl containers: [c++ template class; function with arbitrary container type, how to define it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728478/c-template-class-function-with-arbitrary-container-type-how-to-define-it), with many of them could be easily applied for your case as well.

Comment: The optimal solution imo would be to ditch the `std::function` from the signature entirely. To incure the cost of type erasure (not to mention the effect on TAD) while *still* using a function template is in my book a pessimization. Just add a template parameter `Pred` and declare the function parameter as `Pred shouldRemove`. Everything will just work (TM) from then on (with better inlining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with something based on the [answer provided by Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67711570/3987765) and the [comment posted by StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711481/can-a-function-template-deduce-a-containers-value-type/67711570#comment119684873_67711481). The former provided a solution that handled more than just QSet, while the latter provided a solution that was simpler overall.

```cpp
template<typename ContainerT, typename Pred>
int removeItems(ContainerT& container, Pred shouldRemove)
{
    int numRemoved = 0;

    auto iter = container.begin();
    while (iter != container.end())
    {
        if (shouldRemove(*iter))
        {
            iter = container.erase(iter);
            ++numRemoved;
        }
        else
        {
            ++iter;
        }
    }

    return numRemoved;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can tolerate slightly more aggressive duck-typing, templating on the container itself and extracting the `value_type` within the template gets you there.

```
template<typename ContainerT>
int removeItems(
    ContainerT& set,
    const std::function<bool (const typename ContainerT::value_type&)>& shouldRemove)
{
```

At that point, I would also duck-type the callback as well to get rid of the extra indirection from `std::function`, but there is something to be said for cleaner error messages, so it's a matter of preference.

```
template<typename ContainerT, typename CheckT>
int removeItems(
    ContainerT& set,
    const CheckT& shouldRemove)
{
```

**Edit** For reference, it's worth noting that if it wasn't for that `std::function<>` parameter, the compiler would have been able to infer the type correctly just fine as is. So the following works as well:

```
template<typename TYPE, typename CheckT>
int removeItems(
    QSet<TYPE>& set,
    const CheckT& shouldRemove)
{
```

The `std::function<>` messes things up because the lambda needs to be implicitly converted into a `std::function<>`, and implicitly conversions don't play well with template inference.

- The `value_type` version works because the type of the `std::function<>` is completely determined by the first argument.
- The versions with duck-typed callbacks work because the lambda is used as is without having to go through implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
template<typename SET>
int removeItems(
    SET& set,
    const std::function<bool (const typename SET::key_type&)>& shouldRemove);
```

This will deduce the type:

```
removeItems(stuff, [](const QString& thing) {
    return thing.toLower() == "a";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do so. Just like this:

```
 template<typename T>
 struct do_not_deduce
 {
    using type = T;
 };

 template<typename T>
 using do_not_deduce_t = typename do_not_deduce<T>::type;

 template<typename TYPE>
 int removeItems(
 QSet<TYPE>& set,
 const std::function<bool (const do_not_deduce_t<TYPE>&)>& shouldRemove)
 ....
```

The issue is that `removeItems` attempts to deduce types from both inputs.
Thus passing a lambda as second parameter causes issues with the deduction as it needs to be converted to the correct type of `std::function` which is rather complicated to do during template argument deduction.

In the solution I provided I simply removed the argument deduction from the second parameters thus the deduction is done according to the first parameter only - and subsequently is succeeds.

Notes: you shouldn't use `std::function` for fast checks as it is rather slow.
You'd better accept a general template argument instead and just verify via SFINAE that it is invokable and has correct signature.